# In IE9, for keyup event When I use the enter key "event" is not getting, for other keys Iam getting keycode values

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use  Enter key, `alert("kcode=="+e.which)` the kcode is getting undefined and  the if condition is not executed in IE9.

**In HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

**In JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").keyup(function(e){

        var kcode = e.which || e.keyCode;
       alert("kcode=="+e.which);
        if (kcode == 13){
            alert("in if");
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: provide an MCVE (Read [ask])

Comment: works fine for me using IE 8

Answer (score 1):

It seems that IE has some special keys for which it doesn't trigger 'keyup' when pressed. I found this behavior on IE11 for 'keyup'. Instead, I used 'keypress' and worked fine. I also found other internet posts refering similar situations with IE and other key events.
[this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/keyup-event-doesn-t-work-on-enter-in-ie) is one of them
Hope this helps someone to survive IE issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use window.event in IE. You can try this fiddle I've setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/ytphedvg/

I've tested it in IE9, it works perfectly.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").keyup(function(e){
        var ev = e || window.event;
        var kcode = ev.which || ev.keyCode;
        alert("kcode=="+ev.which);
        if (kcode == 13){
            alert("in if");
        }
    });
});
```